# Variable Dependence scipy.special.genlaguerre

Tags: scipy

I'm new to python. If I wanted L(n, a, x) where L is the general Laguerre polynomial then I could simply use

```
from scipy.special import genlaguerre
print(genlaguerre(n, a))
```

However, I am having trouble obtaining something like L(n, a, 2 pi x) since  there is no explicit variable dependence in the function genlaguerre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object returned by `genlaguerre(n, a)` is callable; you call it to evaluate it at a given `x`.

For example,

```
In [71]: import numpy as np

In [72]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [73]: from scipy.special import genlaguerre

In [74]: n = 3

In [75]: alpha = 4.5

In [76]: L = genlaguerre(n, alpha)
```

To get the value of the polynomial at `x`, call `L(x)`:

```
In [77]: L(0)
Out[77]: 44.6875

In [78]: L(1)
Out[78]: 23.895833333333332

In [79]: L([2, 2.5, 3])
Out[79]: array([ 9.60416667,  4.58333333,  0.8125    ])

In [80]: x = np.linspace(0, 14, 100)

In [81]: plt.plot(x, L(x))
Out[81]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11cde42b0>]

In [82]: plt.xlabel('x')
Out[82]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x11cddc4a8>

In [83]: plt.ylabel('$L_{%d}^{(%g)}(x)$' % (n, alpha))
Out[83]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x11cdce320>

In [84]: plt.grid()
```

Here's the plot generated by the above code:

[image: plot]